# PDO not storing values while in a class

Tags: php, database, class, pdo

I'm a little confused at the moment because my DB class doesn't seem to be storing any results after a query (i.e. the 'results' property is still an empty array). The unsual thing is that when I transfer my logic outside a class definition it works perfectly.

My code with database credentials blanked out:

```
namespace DatabaseConnection;
use PDO;

class DB {

/*****STATES*****/
private $con;
private $results; 


/*****METHODS*****/
public function init(){

    $this->con = new PDO("***************************");
    $this->results = array();

    return $this;
}

public function getInfo(){
    if($this->con === null ) return "No Connection";
    else return "Connected"; 
}

public function getResults(){
    return $this->results;
}



public function retrieve(){
    $query = $this->con->prepare("select * from documents");
        $query->execute(); 


        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $this->results[] = $row;
        }



    return $this;
}
```

Comment: what happens when you replaceyour init() function with public  function __construct(){}  and remove return $this...

Comment: I originally changed my constructor function to init(), because for some reason the PDO object wouldn't initialize when in a standard constructor.

Comment: try DB extends PDO.. and than  parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $passwd, $options) inside your __construct()

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public function retrieve(){
    $query = $this->con->prepare("select * from documents");

    $query->execute();  //<---------

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $this->results[] = $row;
    }

    return $this;
 }
```

OP is **preparing a statement and then never executes** it, and has no way of detecting this because of the utter lack of any error handling on the DB calls. – Marc B

Comment: +1. e.g. OP is preparing a statement and then never executes it, and has no way of detecting this because of the utter lack of any error handling on the DB calls.

Comment: My apologies, I do have an execute in there, but I accidently omitted it during the copy and paste.

Comment: *fixed to reflect the above*
thanks for bringing that to my attention.